# Python Deployment Not Logging Anything

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a discord bot that I have deployed on kubernetes.  It is built into a docker image that I then deploy to k8s.

`Dockerfile`:

```
    FROM python:3.7

    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . /app

    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
    CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

`deployment.yml`:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pythonapp
  labels:
    app: pythonapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pythonapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pythonapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pythonapp
          image: registry.example.com/pythonapp:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: PYTHONUNBUFFERED
              value: "0"
```

When I deploy it, the program runs fine.  But when I go to check the pod's logs, it says `The selected container has not logged any messages yet.`.

How can I get anything that I `print()` in python to be logged to the kubernetes pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PYTHONUNBUFFERED` must be set to `1` if you want to show log messages immediately without being buffered first.